# Azure.RequestFailedException: No such host is known

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an application (aspnet core app 3.1) where I load data during startup from azure blob storage with the following code:

```
BlobClient client = new BlobClient(loaderOptions.ConnectionString, loaderOptions.BlobContainerName, loaderOptions.BlobName);

var response = client.Download();

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
     response.Value.Content.CopyTo(memoryStream);
     return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Locally, on my PC everything works fine. But when I publish this app to azure app service (windows) I get the following errors:

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 6 tries. (No such host is known.) (No such host is known.) (No such host is known.) (No such host is known.) (No such host is known.) (No such host is known.)

 ---> Azure.RequestFailedException: No such host is known.

 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.

 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.

   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)

   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

A week ago everything worked fine. Now I have created new service plans and storage accounts (deleted old ones) and come across this problem.

What can be solution?

[image]

Comment: Are you connecting to same storage account in both local and Azure environment?

Comment: yes, I do, it is strange..

Comment: I’m wondering if your storage account is behind some firewall that’s preventing the access from app service. Can you check that?

Comment: I have checked all networks in firewall settings

Comment: It is indeed weird. Only thing I would suggest is check the settings again in your App Service and you're connecting to the same account.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm having the same issue and the fun thing is that it's happening only on my local machine.

Comment: Hear here - I never get this from debug but often from prod. Intermittent => prod mostly works fine

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue as this. Further analysis would indicate, Local DNS issues. If in doubt trace the address supplied and where needed add a temporary host record in c:\windows